# CodeDeploy sometimes fails without any error messages. Deploy it again and it runs fine

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I have been using CodeDeploy with CodePipeline for quite some time now. All of a sudden I am seeing the deploy fail every once in a while. If I run the deploy again with no changes it will then run fine and pass.

When I look at the deployment lifecycle events in the AWS dashboard they are useless as all they tell me the following:

The original has a status of "Unknown" and when you view the events you see:

```
BeforeBlockTraffic      Unknown
BlockTraffic                Unknown
AfterBlockTraffic       Unknown
```

The replacement has a status of "Failed" and when you view the events it shows you that all the events were skipped.

The failed and passed logs are below.

Codebuild gives no other indication as to why it failed.

Anywhere else to look at for logs or clues as to why it failed?

Thanks for any help!

Here is the contents of code deploy log(/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log) from the instance launched from the failed deployment:

```
2019-09-25 13:08:15 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2061)]: master 2061: Spawned child 1/1
2019-09-25 13:08:16 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2019-09-25 13:08:16 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Archives to retain is: 5}
2019-09-25 13:08:16 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:08:16 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2061)]: Started master 2061 with 1 children
2019-09-25 13:09:16 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.122422 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0dad6d3fcdf0xxxx")

2019-09-25 13:09:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:10:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 61.02391 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0dad6d3fcdf0xxxx")

2019-09-25 13:10:19 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:11:19 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.071791 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0dad6d3fcdf0xxxx")

2019-09-25 13:11:20 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:12:20 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.045927 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0dad6d3fcdf0xxxx")

2019-09-25 13:12:21 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:13:22 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.551739 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0dad6d3fcdf0xxxx")

2019-09-25 13:13:23 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:14:23 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2065)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.627054 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0dad6d3fcdf0xxxx")

"/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log" [readonly] 38L, 4545C
```

Here is the log from the successful deployment that was run on the same setup right after the failed deployment :

```
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2036)]: master 2036: Spawned child 1/1
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Archives to retain is: 5}
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.074098 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.028728 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uU3RvcCIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6MSwiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.015252 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Revision",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:17 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.014355 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uU3RvcCIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6MSwiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:20:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2036)]: Started master 2036 with 1 children
2019-09-25 13:20:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.045746 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.025593 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkRvd25sb2FkQnVuZGxlIiwiY29tbWFuZFBvc2l0aW9uIjoyLCJjb21tYW5kQXR0ZW1wdCI6MX1d")

2019-09-25 13:20:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:18 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.024258 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Revision",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:19 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:38 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:38 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.056778 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkRvd25sb2FkQnVuZGxlIiwiY29tbWFuZFBvc2l0aW9uIjoyLCJjb21tYW5kQXR0ZW1wdCI6MX1d")

2019-09-25 13:20:38 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 19.272478 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:38 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:38 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.172167 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkJlZm9yZUluc3RhbGwiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjMsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:20:38 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.199375 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Revision",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:39 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: /aws/scripts/before_install.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.018422 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkJlZm9yZUluc3RhbGwiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjMsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.084844 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.031777 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6Ikluc3RhbGwiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjQsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:39 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.01897 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Revision",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:40 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.026985 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6Ikluc3RhbGwiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjQsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:20:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 13.004045 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.041782 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFmdGVySW5zdGFsbCIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6NSwiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:20:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:53 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.01711 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Revision",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:53 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: /aws/scripts/after_install.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.017418 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFmdGVySW5zdGFsbCIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6NSwiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.051494 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.026478 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uU3RhcnQiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjYsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:54 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.016735 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Revision",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:54 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: /aws/scripts/application_start.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
2019-09-25 13:20:55 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.024182 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uU3RhcnQiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjYsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.905537 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.029999 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IlZhbGlkYXRlU2VydmljZSIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6NywiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.026361 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"CodeDeploy/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Revision",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:20:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.015475 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTIvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1JVFlZUEM4T05fUmV2aXNpb24iLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTI6NDk5MDAwODgxOTM2Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDQ5N2MyZTg4MDYyZjgxNjEiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IlZhbGlkYXRlU2VydmljZSIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6NywiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:20:57 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:21:01 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 4.050164 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:21:01 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:21:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.046346 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiRmxpcERlcGxveW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VyL3VzLWVhc3QtMi9Qcm9kL2Fybjphd3M6c2RzOnVzLWVhc3QtMjo0OTkwMDA4ODE5MzY6ZGVwbG95bWVudC9kLUlUWVlQQzhPTl9GbGlwLUdyZWVuIiwiaG9zdElkIjoiYXJuOmF3czplYzI6dXMtZWFzdC0yOjQ5OTAwMDg4MTkzNjppbnN0YW5jZS9pLTA0OTdjMmU4ODA2MmY4MTYxIiwiY29tbWFuZE5hbWUiOiJCZWZvcmVBbGxvd1RyYWZmaWMiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjEsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:21:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:21:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.030583 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"FlipDeploymentManager/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Flip-Green",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:21:02 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: /aws/scripts/before_allow_traffic.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
2019-09-25 13:21:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:21:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.026595 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiRmxpcERlcGxveW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VyL3VzLWVhc3QtMi9Qcm9kL2Fybjphd3M6c2RzOnVzLWVhc3QtMjo0OTkwMDA4ODE5MzY6ZGVwbG95bWVudC9kLUlUWVlQQzhPTl9GbGlwLUdyZWVuIiwiaG9zdElkIjoiYXJuOmF3czplYzI6dXMtZWFzdC0yOjQ5OTAwMDg4MTkzNjppbnN0YW5jZS9pLTA0OTdjMmU4ODA2MmY4MTYxIiwiY29tbWFuZE5hbWUiOiJCZWZvcmVBbGxvd1RyYWZmaWMiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjEsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2019-09-25 13:21:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:22:04 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 61.159342 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")



2019-09-25 13:23:34 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:23:34 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.105599 0 retries] put_host_command_acknowledgement(diagnostics:nil,host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiRmxpcERlcGxveW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VyL3VzLWVhc3QtMi9Qcm9kL2Fybjphd3M6c2RzOnVzLWVhc3QtMjo0OTkwMDA4ODE5MzY6ZGVwbG95bWVudC9kLUlUWVlQQzhPTl9GbGlwLUdyZWVuIiwiaG9zdElkIjoiYXJuOmF3czplYzI6dXMtZWFzdC0yOjQ5OTAwMDg4MTkzNjppbnN0YW5jZS9pLTA0OTdjMmU4ODA2MmY4MTYxIiwiY29tbWFuZE5hbWUiOiJBZnRlckFsbG93VHJhZmZpYyIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6MywiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:23:34 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:23:34 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.038098 0 retries] get_deployment_specification(deployment_execution_id:"FlipDeploymentManager/us-east-2/Prod/arn:aws:sds:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:deployment/d-ITYYPC8ON_Flip-Green",host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")

2019-09-25 13:23:34 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::HookExecutor: Script at specified location: /aws/scripts/after_allow_traffic.sh is not executable.  Trying to make it executable.
2019-09-25 13:23:35 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:23:36 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_rpm.
2019-09-25 13:23:36 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.047799 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Succeeded",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":0,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Succeeded\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiRmxpcERlcGxveW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VyL3VzLWVhc3QtMi9Qcm9kL2Fybjphd3M6c2RzOnVzLWVhc3QtMjo0OTkwMDA4ODE5MzY6ZGVwbG95bWVudC9kLUlUWVlQQzhPTl9GbGlwLUdyZWVuIiwiaG9zdElkIjoiYXJuOmF3czplYzI6dXMtZWFzdC0yOjQ5OTAwMDg4MTkzNjppbnN0YW5jZS9pLTA0OTdjMmU4ODA2MmY4MTYxIiwiY29tbWFuZE5hbWUiOiJBZnRlckFsbG93VHJhZmZpYyIsImNvbW1hbmRQb3NpdGlvbiI6MywiY29tbWFuZEF0dGVtcHQiOjF9XQ==")

2019-09-25 13:24:36 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2040)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.278552 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:4900xxxxxxxx:instance/i-0497c2e88062fxxxx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting code deploy agents resolve the same problem for me.